# $\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to show that
$$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=0,$$ where $x,y,z>0$.

My attempt:

$$||(x,y,z)|| < \delta \implies |x|, |y|, |z| < \delta$$
$$\left | \frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \right | < \left | \frac{xyz}{x^2}\right | < \frac{\delta^3}{x^2}.$$

Now, I do not know how to proceed, and I think my attempt might be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $|x|\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, $|y|\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, and $|z|\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Hence, given $\varepsilon>0$,

$$ \left| \frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right|\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}<\varepsilon$$

whenever $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+x^2}<\delta=\varepsilon$.

And we are done!

Answer (score 3):

Using A-G inequality, $x^2+y^2+z^2\geq3(xyz)^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Comment: A more general way is let $x=r\sin\varphi\cos\theta, y=x=r\sin\varphi\sin\theta, z=r\cos\theta$, then let $r\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @user8w3011 Use of polar coordinates is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I think it's a commonly-used and convenient way to solve limits of rational functions like this, maybe this is just my opnion.